# MS Access file size limitation error despite linking tables from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2016, import-csv

I have SQL Server tables (backend) linked to my MS Access frontend.

I am trying to import 9GB CSV file to my linked SQL Server table but in the middle of the importing I get file size limitation error, that my access file has exceeded 2 GB?!!!

What am I doing wrong here?

I tried to link my CSV file directly to MS Access and it worked but then I will have to use an append query to do the importing process by appending to my sql server table.

I would like to understand why I am getting this error

Comment: My apologies after I linked my CSV file directly, I opened the table but it was not imported correctly, all rows showed #Num value

Comment: It is better to load *.csv file into SQL Server directly, i.e. without any front-end. (1) T-SQL, (2) bcp.exe, or (3) SSIS.

Comment: @Yitzhak Khabinsky I made more research and I suspect the the problem is not with the file size it is with the ram allocated for the process itself. Any ideas about that? thank you for your reply and I will consider as my last solution because I am having other problems with this solution

Comment: What I suggested ##1-3, it doesn't require that much RAM.